# HttpClient upload file without multipart in .net

Tags: c#, upload, httpclient

I am using HttpCilent (System.Net.Http). What I am seeing is, there is no way to post a file content in request body. I have to use multipart content to add file there and upload. The api I am calling does not support multipart file content and I have to put file content in the request body itself. Along with file, I do need to add access token and other client data(json). Is there anyway here that I can supply the filebytes along with access token and other cilent data (json)?

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
 BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint);
};
var result = await client.PostAsync("api/storage/upload?fileName=test.csv", fileBytes);
```

Comment: You could base64 encode the file contents and send the encoded string as part of the json.

Comment: Sounds like the API is not HTTP compliant.  Is there documentation on the API that shows how the request body should look?

Comment: Hi @stephan The api expects file in bytes. I will however try as you said to pass it as json and in base64 though.

Comment: @richard The api doc says that it does not support multipart file upload. Along with that, it only accepts file inside request body. And file name will be conveyed by query string parameter.  What I understand is, there can't be two request body for sure. One to hold access token and client data and one to file content.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Try replacing `fileBytes` with `new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes)`.  You can set any necessary Headers on ByteArrayContent object if needed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.bytearraycontent(v=vs.118).aspx